# Horizontally Centering image of *any* width with CSS

Tags: css, centering

I am trying to horizontally center images of *any* width. (In other words, each image has a width that falls in a range between 100px and 1000px). The parent area is 712px wide.

Most solutions I've tried center the images left side at the 50% mark.

Comment: Why not do it dynamically with javascript/jquery?

Comment: @Araymer There are definitely CSS-only ways to do it. Using a JS-based solution is heavy-handed, IMHO.

Comment: Centering dynamically-sized content with CSS?

Starts to get into "hacky" sort of territory in my opinion, when you can use a single line of Jquery.

Comment: Does all images have same height or does the parent has a predefined height as well?

Comment: And if height is predefined, what should happen when image is higher than parent, center or top align?

Comment: @Araymer CSS is meant for styling, script is not, and when CSS can't do what one want (is still somewhat limited but we get there), a script hack might.

Comment: If you have to write two div containers and float them and then twiddle with those things just for a single position, it's obviously not meant to do that thing.

I never understood the obsession with creating best practices that are more complicated than necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

or:

```
div.your-block-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}
div.your-block-wrapper img {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Also add **max-width:100%**

Comment: What if image is wider than container?

Comment: Nope, that will not work. Try and you'll see. Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/46mdr2z6/2/

Comment: This did in fact work, once I reset the caption nonsense out of the <div>. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

This `margin-left:50%; transform:translate(-50%,0);` will position the element in the middle of its container. Even container is smaller than image:

```css
div { width:100%; overflow-x:hidden; border:1px solid }

div > img { margin-left:50%; transform:translate(-50%,0); vertical-align:middle; }
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
</div>

<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/600/sports/3/">
</div>
```

Comment: This *should* work. First thing I tried. But this also lines all images up by their left side at the 50% mark (of the 712px column.) Elegant solution though. Thanks

Comment: @r.benari  I am not sure I understand you here. Could you show fiddle with the problem?

Comment: @r.benari This one **does** work, +1, and unfortunately is better than mine :) as you don't need to set the height on the parent.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.ct {
    position: relative;
 width: 700px;
 height: 700px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.ct img {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 width: 900px;
 margin-left: -450px;
 z-index: 22;
}
```

```html
<div class="ct">
    <img src="http://images.entertainment.ie/images_content/rectangle/620x372/success-kid.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

This apparently is something that's been floating around some of my dev friends that they've been adopting. I will likely start giving this a shot. It's still CSS, it's clean and no script required. You can also vertically center (and other stuff, as well).

Answer (score -1):

You could do it like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/46mdr2z6/1/

```
    <div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x110">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/650x250">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/850x350">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x750">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/520x270">
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 712px
}
.wrapper > div{
  text-align: center;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This does not make image wider than 712px grow wider than its parent: https://jsfiddle.net/46mdr2z6/2/

Comment: With the price of additional DOM element :(

Comment: Transform renders slower. Also I assumed that the 712px would be the max-width. If it needs to grow bigger you can just remove the max-width.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you remove max-width, still wont work. Try it before you say it will work.

Comment: @joke12345 If you will remove max-width there you will have problems : https://jsfiddle.net/ocw2u1qs/

Comment: It does grow bigger on Safari here. Also the OP did not ask for the div to grow. If you need any help feel free to ask a new question and I would be happy to help.

Comment: The whole point with the question is it should grow wider than its parent if image is wider than 712px  **and** still stay centered. If not we wouldn't have this question as that is an easy task.